# Saving of runtime application Log

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have implemented one transit Application in C++ language.

Actually this application has many issue like like Slowness when ticket generation, random Crash... etc.

So i want to save that log in file with 1kb size.

So i want to know How to save runtime log in file ?

Comment: This depends on your OS and specific compiler

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot modify the application ("can not debug") then your only source of data is whatever the application currently logs.  Otherwise you need to reply on features of your operating system.  On linux, for instance, a crashed process will generate a core file unless it's disabled via `ulimit -c0`.  The other tool of interest would be tracing of the kernel, so you can capture at run-time.  Again, on Linux, you want to look at eBPF.  You may also want to look a resource utilization (memory, network, disk etc).

Comment: How to create run time kernel trace in application and store it into file ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166541/how-to-know-where-a-program-is-stuck-in-linux/166580#166580

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages describe how the program behaves when it runs. When the program crashes, there's nothing that you can do in in the language, because the program is no longer running. As such, creation of such file is entirely external to the programming language itself.

The file that you describe is typically called a memory dump, core dump or similar name. Each computer system has their own dump format, and their own configuration for their creation. So, the first step is to know the system where your program is going to be run.

Comment: Note that for many people here, "crash" might mean encountered undefined behavior in some form, but for other users it might mean any unwanted termination of the program, including for example an `assert` that detects a problem, prints an error to a log file, and terminates before serious damage can be done. To me at least, it isn't quite clear what the OP means.